# Unwanted UIView Created Automatically with UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I am working on an app in the storyboard and building the basic layout. I had a dynamic prototype cell in a `UITableView` which I created a view in because I thought it would be a good idea to constrain some items in the cell with a view. When I tried to delete that view, I could not. I could not even move any other views outside of it.

I deleted the entire cell and tried to make a new one but even the new one had the view in it, name name too. Everything I tried to put in the cell was automatically put in the view as well.

Now the view is causing me problems because it's height is static and everything is constrained by it. It also seems to take on the roll as superview since everything is inside of it. So any time I constrain anything to the super view, such as the leading edge to superview constraint, it will actually be constrained to the leading edge of that view.

Why is the view being created whenever I make a cell? I have a feeling that it is some setting I mistakenly set but I looked through all of the settings of the view and and cell.

How do I get rid of this view that seems to be tied to every cell?

Comment: [A Closer Look at Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. The default view in all cells was actually added after that article but it led me in the right direction to find out that after iOS 8 all cells are automatically created with a view that acts as the superview.

Comment: Glad it helped, although if you mean the `contentView` it's been there since iOs 2, and if you were working with the actual cell superview - that might be not the best idea as the `UITableView` "internal" subviews structure is known to change once in a while.